# How to translate for of with array from JavaScript to Python

Tags: javascript, python

I am working on translating some JavaScript code that a business partner wrote to Python. I am somewhat familiar with JavaScript and very unfamiliar with Python, but have been making good progress until I ran across some code that I haven't seen before in JavaScript.

```
let recordTypesSet = new Set();
for (let [errorType, accountList] of errors) {
  for (let i = 0; i < accountList.length; i = i + 1) {
    let error = accountList[i];
    recordTypesSet.add(error.recordType);
  }
}
```

I am not sure what the second line is doing really. I know that for of iterates over iterable objects as per mdn, but I haven't seen it done before with an array as is shown here. I was hoping someone could clarify what that line is doing and maybe an example of how to do that the pythonic way as well.

Have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

You are looking at a [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).
What is happening is that `errors` is an array of arrays, and each element is of size 2.
In each for cycle iteration you take that element and instead of calling `element[0]` and `element[1]` on it, you already give it meaningful names.

Comment: Incredible, you're correct. I think I need to take a step back and understand the code and business logic a bit more, and I would have figured that out. Thanks for this!

Comment: I'm glad I could be of help! Could you mark my answer as correct then? This way more people looking for the same thing will find it (also gamification ftw)